# Camel File Sequence Numbers

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'd have thought this was a fairly common use case, but I have not seen anything in the Camel documentation. I looked at the re-sequencer, but that did not seem suitable.

1. I have a route that receives files from a 3rd party. The file name contains a sequence number. Files *must* be processed in sequence. No sequence numbers can be skipped.
2. If a file is received that is > than the expected sequence, then I want to skip it and wait for the correct sequence number. This could then be reprocessed after the expected sequence number was received.
3. If a file is received that is < than the expected sequence, then this would be an error.

What would be the best technique to use for this?

I would obviously need to track the last processed / next expected sequence number. How would you do this so that the route can be stopped etc, and retain knowledge of what sequence to expect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did the resequencer not suit your needs?

Comment: my understanding was that the sequencer would be used where I have a batch of messages to process, and can identify the sequence. It does not seem to have anything to know what the next sequence number should be, or detect 'missed' files.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Paul, well your filename contains the sequence number, right? If so, then there should be a way to make this to work with the sequencer. We have used a similar "detect skipped sequence number" mechanism myself, but we did it with hazelcast and some simple expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a resequencer (plus a Processor) to do this.

Firstly, some things to keep in mind: from camel 2.11, the resequencer can be configured to reject "old" messages, but it won't (as far as I can see) detect "skipped" messages (e.g. message 2,3,5 - skipped 4), so you need to add an extra check for this via a custom processor.

```
from("direct:myFiles")
        .bean(SetSequenceNumber.class)  // set header "seqnum" of type Long
        .resequence(header("seqnum")).stream().timeout(5000).rejectOld()
        .process(new Processor() {
            Long lastSeq;
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                Long seqnum = exchange.getIn().getHeader("seqnum", Long.class);
                if (lastSeq == null) {
                    lastSeq = seqnum;
                } else {
                    if (seqnum != lastSeq + 1) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Skipped sequence number between " + lastSeq + " and " + seqnum);
                    }
                    lastSeq = seqnum;
                }
            }
        })
        .log("Resequenced: ${header.seqnum}")
;
```

Basically, you can extract the sequence number from your filename and set it as a header named `seqnum`. Then you send it through the resequencer, specifying a timeout. Then it goes through your processor to detected skipped sequence numbers.

I hope this helps.

Comment: OK. I will give that a try. After re-reading the doco, I believe the 'Stream Re-sequencing' may also help me with the skipped numbers. How does it know what sequence to expect at the beginning?

Comment: I do think that "any" sequence number at the beginning is accepted.

Comment: After more consideration, I have changed my approach and have instead used a File Filter (see [link](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)). The 'next expected' sequence is stored externally.